# I want to get the child of my firebase (not the key) using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my firebase. I want to retrieve the names "anaesthesia", "musculoskeletal", "options" into an array and print it out. This is my swift code

```
        ref?.child("mcqbase-159dc").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){
              for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                self.categoriesArray.append(key)
                print(self.categoriesArray)
                }
            }
        })
```

It returns a blank in my terminal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"anaesthesia", "musculoskeletal" and other your database table's names. You can change your structure to :

[image]

And your snapshot code must be :

```
Database.database().reference().child("names").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
  
   //Your code
    }
```